# Linq to Sql: Can I return the Identity_Scope after an insert?

Tags: linq-to-sql, identity-column

After I do an insert using linq to sql, can I get the Identity_scope value back if my table has an identity column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linq to SQL does the job for you, the identity value it's available just after the `SubmitChanges` method is called.

```
var entity = new Entity();
// ...
ctx.Entities.InsertOnSubmit(entity);
ctx.SubmitChanges();
// Here you can use the generated value of yout identity column

entity.Id;
```

Comment: It was way to obvious for me to see :) Thanks.